# Unary predicate to check for a character being in string

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

I'm reading [*Real World Haskell*](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/), and I tried to implement the `splitLines` code myself, and I came up with more or less the same implementation ([Chapter 4](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html), page 73):

```
splitLines :: String -> [String]
splitLines [] = []
splitLines ('\r':a) = splitLines a
splitLines ('\n':a) = splitLines a
splitLines       a  = let (l,r) = break isCRorNL a
                      in l:splitLines r
                      where isCRorNL e = ???
--the book defines isCRorNL c = c == '\n' || c == '\r'
```

However, I've been spending definitely too much time trying to write the `isCRorNL` in the most functional and readable way I could think of, so that I can get rid of the `where` and turning the last definition of `splitLines` into an amost-english sentence (just like `` compare `on` length `` and the likes), without success.

Some sparse thoughts I have been going through:

- A lambda, `(\c -> c == '\n' || c == '\r')`, is just too much power and too little expressiveness for such a simple and specific task;
- furthermore, it contains a fair amount of duplicated code and/or it is uselessly verbose.
- Whatever I have to put in `isCRorNL` has to have type `Char -> Bool`,
- therefore it can have any type `a1 -> a2 -> ... -> an -> Char -> Bool` if I provide it with the first `n` arguments.
- The `any` function can help me checking if a *given* character is either `'\n'` or `'\r'` or, in other words, if it is in the list of `Char`s `"\n\r"`.
- Since I want to check for equality, I can pass `(==)` to my function.
- Therefore `isCRorNL` can have type `(Char -> Char -> Bool) -> [Char] -> Char -> Bool` (or with the first two argument inverted), and I can pass to it `(==)` as the first argument and `"\n\r"` as the second argument.
- So I was looking for some standard functions I could compose to get such a function.

Finally I gave up and defined it this way: `isCRorNL e = any (== e) "\n\r"`; I think this is quite good as regards extensibility, as I can add as many characters in the `"…"`, and I can change the operator `==`; sadly I cannot put the function directly where it is used, as I am not able to write it as a partially applied function.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as I looked for the link in the question and visited it (for the first time), I realized that the code chunks are commented by readers, and the first comment under `splitLines` reads:

> augustss 2008-04-23
>
> [...] If you're making a point about functional
>   style maybe you should use
>
> ```
> isLineSeparator = (`elem` "\r\n")
> ```

So it comes out I was thinking to much about composition of functions, while the easiest solution lies in the partial application of a so simple function, `elem`. The drawback here is that the operator used to check for equality is built in `elem` and cannot be changed. Nonetheless I feel dumb for not having thought to `elem` myself.